# WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet Docker Container : libgdiplus.so No such file or directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, dockerfile

https://github.com/HakanL/WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet?tab=readme-ov-file
I see Code use Docker container ( I work Project in MacBook  Project C# .NET Core )

Docker
If you are using a linux version of docker container for net core provided from microsoft, you will need to install a couple of libraries.

The following example is for debian based linux distros;

Insert the below lines before the WORKDIR /app command

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y libgdiplus
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdiplus.so
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zlib1g fontconfig libfreetype6 libx11-6 libxext6 libxrender1 wget gdebi
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN gdebi --n wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN apt install libssl1.1
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.so /usr/lib/libwkhtmltox.so

I Insert in DockerFile.

I get to my project and Error
Display :

---

> [ticketservice.api base  4/10] RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdiplus.so:
> 0.179 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdiplus.so': No such file or directory

---

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdiplus.so" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

"libgdiplus.so" is No found,How do I fix it?

I want to use NugetPackage  Haukcode.WkHtmlToPdfDotNet.  in C# .NET Core